# How can I change check to uncheck on this Checkbox case?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Please, help me here... I have a list of checkboxes with "isChecked" value from DB, but I don't know how change this value when I pressed the checkbox. (Ex. If I have one checkbox with isChecked value "false", when I want to press it, the isChecked value needs to change "true"

Thank you!!!

```js
renderServicesContent = section => {
    let taskrendered = [];
    let checked      = false;
    checks = this.state.isChecked;
    updateTasks    = this.state.updateTaks;
    section.default_tasks.map(function(elemen, index) {
      concatService = elemen.description ;
      if (elemen.verified == 1 || elemen.verified == 2) {
        checked = true;
      } else {
        checked = false;
      }
      let disabledCheck = false;
      if(section.status == "4"){
        disabledCheck = true;
      }else{
        disabledCheck = false;
      }
        taskrendered.push(
                <ListItem>
                <CheckBox
                    style = {{flex: 1, padding: 10}}
                    onClick = {() => {this.updateTasks(elemen)}
                    isChecked = {checked}
                    rightText = {concatService}
                    disabled = {disabledCheck}
                />
                </ListItem>
        );
    });
    
    return (
      <View>
        {taskrendered}
      </View>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the `CheckBox` component from @react-native/community? If so, it contains a prop `onValueChanged` that could help you solve that problem. For more info you can review their documentation here: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-checkbox.

If you're using `CheckBox` from react-native directly, you should consider switching the the one in @react-native/community, since react-native deprecated theirs (as per their documentation here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/checkbox#__docusaurus).

Answer (score 0):

Try with value attribute in Checkbox component.

```
value={this.state.isChecked}
```